# Download file without asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

I wanted to know if there is a way to download a file to an android devices without using an async task.

My problem is that I want to use an async task in my app, and i need to call a download function INSIDE this asyncTask, but android's documentation says that it is only possible to create an asyncTask from the UI thread.

I tried creating a thread by using `extends thread` instead of `extends asyncTask`, but android still gave the "Network on UI thread exception".

I need a function that works like this: String downloadFile(String url){...} that returns the downloaded String (i'm downloading an xml file, nothing fancy)

Comment: Please post your AsyncTask code. It is still the easiest way to do such things, so let's make it work.

Comment: Best guess is that your AsyncTask implementation is not right...

Comment: unclear. if you are on the uithread, you can execute an asynctask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and i need to call a download function INSIDE this asyncTask

If "INSIDE this asyncTask" really means "from the `doInBackground()` method of the `AsyncTask`", then the "download function" (whatever *that* is) does not need to be asynchronous.

> but android still said the "Network on UI thread exception"

Then you are not doing the network I/O from `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask` or by any background means (e.g., from a regular `Thread` that you fork).

Answer (score 0):

You can Services to download a file in Android.

A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use. Each service class must have a corresponding  declaration in its package's AndroidManifest.xml. Services can be started with Context.startService() and Context.bindService().

Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work. More information on this can be found in Processes and Threads. The IntentService class is available as a standard implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules its work to be done.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/FileDownloadService.htm

Comment: IMO using a service isn't what the OP wants to do for his app, he does need to use an AsyncTask but is going about it the wrong way. Using a service is unnecessary overhead, which is still in the UI thread (unless he creates a thread, which you've said, but that defeats the object of moving it to a service)